# How can i use the Mantine UI template in react js its saying INTERFACE is a reserve word How do i change that?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frameworks, mantine

How can i use the Mantine UI template in react js its saying INTERFACE is a reserve word How do i change that ?

I want to use the Mantine template from the official website but not every template works some that Have the INTERFACE function on them can't seem to work because javscript says INTERFACE is a reserved keyword how do i edit it to work.

```
import { createStyles, Paper, Text, Title, Button } from '@mantine/core';

const useStyles = createStyles((theme) => ({
  card: {
    height: 440,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
  },

  title: {
    fontFamily: `Greycliff CF ${theme.fontFamily}`,
    fontWeight: 900,
    color: theme.white,
    lineHeight: 1.2,
    fontSize: 32,
    marginTop: theme.spacing.xs,
  },

  category: {
    color: theme.white,
    opacity: 0.7,
    fontWeight: 700,
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
}));

interface ArticleCardImageProps {
  image: string;
  title: string;
  category: string;
}

export function ArticleCardImage({ image, title, category }: ArticleCardImageProps) {
  const { classes } = useStyles();

  return (
    <Paper
      shadow="md"
      p="xl"
      radius="md"
      sx={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}
      className={classes.card}
    >
      <div>
        <Text className={classes.category} size="xs">
          {category}
        </Text>
        <Title order={3} className={classes.title}>
          {title}
        </Title>
      </div>
      <Button variant="white" color="dark">
        Read article
      </Button>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The examples provided use TypeScript. `interface` in this case is a TypeScript construct (not the javascript reserved word) and you're trying to use it outside of TypeScript scope. In order to use the example with pure javascript, remove all the typing information:

```
import { createStyles, Paper, Text, Title, Button } from '@mantine/core';

const useStyles = createStyles((theme) => ({
  card: {
    height: 440,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
  },

  title: {
    fontFamily: `Greycliff CF ${theme.fontFamily}`,
    fontWeight: 900,
    color: theme.white,
    lineHeight: 1.2,
    fontSize: 32,
    marginTop: theme.spacing.xs,
  },

  category: {
    color: theme.white,
    opacity: 0.7,
    fontWeight: 700,
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
}));


export function ArticleCardImage({ image, title, category }) {
  const { classes } = useStyles();

  return (
    <Paper
      shadow="md"
      p="xl"
      radius="md"
      sx={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}
      className={classes.card}
    >
      <div>
        <Text className={classes.category} size="xs">
          {category}
        </Text>
        <Title order={3} className={classes.title}>
          {title}
        </Title>
      </div>
      <Button variant="white" color="dark">
        Read article
      </Button>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```